# I am trying to build an task app with MERN stack but in frontend my task are not showing on the dashboard of my app here is my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb

```
<Box mt="2rem">
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    {tasks.map((task, idx) => (
    <Grid item xs={12} md={3} key={`${idx}-${task.id}`}>
      <Link
         style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
         to={`/task/${task._id}`}
      ><Task task={task} /></Link>
       </Grid>
     ))}
   </Grid>
</Box>
```

export default Home;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNiB3.png)

I want know where the error is occurring or what is the problem itself.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MERN, but assuming `tasks` is not an empty array, the code you shared looks ok. Perhaps the problem lies in `Task` component - could you share it?

Comment: here is the task component

Comment: const Task = ({ task }) => {
    return (
      <Box sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
        <Card>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                {task.name}
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                Date: {task.date.split("T")[0]}
              </Typography>
              <Typography sx={{ p: 0 }}>{task.type}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
      </Box>
    );
  };

Comment: You should have added the Task component code to the question, because formatting is lost in comments, but I managed to copy it to my IDE and format it there. Everything seems to be just fine and I dont see why it wouldn't work. These are steps you can try further: 1. check the Console - perhaps there is some warning explaining the situation 2. `console.log(tasks)`, see if it's indeed not empty, 3. reproduce the problem in a sandbox, e.g. codesandbox.io and share the link in the question